# php path in mvc htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

Im trying to make a menu in a mvc structure..
The problem is that i have the site in a subdir, in my web root like:

localhost/subdir/

but when i click i link it goes back to my root. the menu is called in a model(static at the momment), in a associative array where the key is the link name, and the value is the path name, like so:

```
 $this->viewModel->set("mainMenu",array("Forside" => "/home", "Hj&aelig;lp" => "/help"));
```

I when call it in a view file:

```
        foreach ($viewModel->get('mainMenu') as $key =>  $values){
              echo '<a href="'. $values. '">' . $key . '</a> ';
        }
```

My .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on



RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

I have tried to make my links with a backslash, that dosen't work.. 
I have tried to make the links with no slash that works alsong as I am in localhost/subdir/home , but when i go to localhost/subdir/home/view,
and click the home link it just goes to localhost/subdir/home/home

I've have tried defining a BASE_ROOT, dosen't work.
And same with defining my DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR don't work :(

Sorry for my bad english, i really hope someone can help me here.

Comment: What is location of `index.php` and .htaccess? Are they in `/subdir/` OR at root level?

Comment: they are in the subdir

Comment: ok provided an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your links absolute i.e. starting with a slash as: `/home`, `/help` etc.

**Add this rule in your `/DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^subdir /subdir/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

**Remember this goes in parent directory of `subdir`**

Comment: well it worked sort of, now then i click  on the links it still sends me to my root, but i can see the views .. i might help if you could look at the project.. you can download it at: https://github.com/ndavison/Nathan-MVC.. its under /classes/basemodel.php and under /views/maintemplate.php and ofc htacces in the root :)

Comment: I will try that once I get back to my computer. Meanwhile I have edited my answer, can you try it now?

Comment: epic it worked thanks alot :), I've really been struggling with this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ocalhost/subdir/$1 [L]
```